# Activeadmin : Check boxes return the object and not the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My models

```
# agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agency_prices
  has_many :agency_cities
  has_many :prices, through: :agency_prices
  has_many :cities, through: :agency_cities
end

# price.rb
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agency_prices
  has_many :agencies, through: :agency_prices
end
```

My activeadmin agency file

```
# admin/agency.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
   permit_params :name,
                 city_ids: [],
                 price_ids: []

   form do |f|

     f.inputs "Agencies" do
       f.input :name
       f.input :cities, as: :check_boxes, checked: City.pluck(&:id)
       f.input :prices, as: :check_boxes, checked: Price.pluck(&:price_range)
     end
   f.actions
  end
end
```

My problem

Although for City the check boxes show the 'name' field of my table "cities", for the Price, the check boxes show the object `#<Price:0x007f6f1dbe9b58>` instead of the price_range field in my table prices.

The code is the same for City and Price, and everything seems right in my tables / join tables.

Do you have an idea of what I can look for ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Price` model, add a `name` method like this:

```
def name
  self.price_range
end
```